# How to code custom excerpt function using mb_substr to return 140 multibyte characters in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, multibyte

I am not quite sure what I am doing, but found this code on-line for a custom excerpt as I am trying to return 140 multibyte Japanese characters on a custom front page in WordPress.  It may be that I do not have the strip_tags function.  If so, can someone please tell me what I need to do to get this to work?  Thank you.

```
front.php -
<?php
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query('showposts=5');
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo winexcerpt(140); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>


functions.php - 
function winexcerpt( $length ) {
   global $post;
   $content = mb_substr(strip_tags($post-&gt;post_content),0,$length);
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: What specific error message are you getting?

Comment: There is no error, but the page does not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strip_tags has been built into PHP since version 4, so it's very unlikely that this is the issue. (That said, if you don't have [multibyte string support enabled](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php), the mb_substr will fail.)

However, it looks like there's been an error when you've copy/pasted the code - the "`-&gt;`" part within the strip_tags line should be a "`->`".

i.e.: Within the winexcerpt function, the line should be:

```
$content = mb_substr(strip_tags($post->post_content),0,$length);
```

As such, it might be as simple as fixing that error.

Comment: I tried the "->", but it does not work.  Any more recommendations?

Comment: @tokyowp - There will be an error in the error logs (or you may have to enable "display_errors" in your php.ini and restart Apache). Without knowing what the specific error is, it's impossible to provide any more help. (I presume you've checked that you have the multibyte functions enabled?)